# How to use Django request to get real domain name when proxy_pass in NGINX

Tags: django, nginx

I use docker and nginx to run my system but I am hitting an issue now to where I would like to redirect client users of my system automatically to a subdomain. i.e. something like `prod.example.com`. This already works in my nginx config to duplicate access to the page, but I would like to map specific `client` urls to the subdomain, not the main one.

Normally this would be simple in Django using something like:

```
if not 'prod.' in request.get_host():
    redirect(f'app.{request.get_host()}')
    # example #  get_host()=app | get_absolute_ur()=http://app/, meta: app
```

But my nginx proxy pass uses an upstream variable, and it appears that is all that is posted through with the variables tried above. How can I get this done?

```
upstream app {
    server web:8000; # appserver_ip:ws_port
}

server {
    server_name prod.example.com;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    # enforces HSTS or only content from https can be served. We do this in CloudFlare
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header Permissions-Policy "autoplay=(), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=(), geolocation=(), microphone=(), browsing-topics=(), midi=()" always;


    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

            }
}
```

Comment: This will probably get you along. You need to also define a setting in settings.py as specified in the short description. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-x-forwarded-host https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay @nigel239 gave me the solution via nice links to documentation. Overall the idea was to pass an `X-Forwarded-Host` value to my NGINX config for each server block -> location:

```
upstream app {
    server web:8000; # appserver_ip:ws_port
}
server {
    # example.com is main site, prod.example.com is the system
    server_name example.com prod.example.com;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    # enforces HSTS or only content from https can be served. We do this in CloudFlare
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header Permissions-Policy "autoplay=(), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=(), geolocation=(), microphone=(), browsing-topics=(), midi=()" always;


    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

            }
}
```

Then in settings.py use: `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True`

Then in my middleware I was able to use the `request.META` values to grab that as so:

```
class RedirectMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
            # print('key loaded middleware', session_key)
            # print(request.path, resolve(request.path_info).kwargs)
            kwargs = resolve(request.path_info).kwargs
            if 'client_url' in kwargs:
                client = ClientInformation.objects.filter(url_base=kwargs['client_url']).last()
                if client:
                    # using this to ensure clients go to app....
                    if settings.PROD:
                        if request.META and request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'):
                            # we hold this reference
                            if request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST', '') != 'prod.example.com':
                                # redirect
                                proto = 'https' # still passed in but we know what it should be
                                host = 'prod.example.com'
                                path = request.get_full_path()
                                url_to_redirect_to = f'{proto}://{host}{path}'
                                print(url_to_redirect_to)
                                return redirect(url_to_redirect_to, permanent=True)
                            else:
                                pass
                    # print('client url found')
                    request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)
                    request.client = client
```

Comment: You can put both server names in one line: `server_name prod.example.com example.com;` :) Have a good one!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment; I saw you hardcoded your headers. When using multiple server names it's probably better to use the `$host` variable in the X-Forwarded-Host header instead.

Comment: @nigel239 updated, originally I was just getting it to work, thanks again!