# How to deploy a multi domain/language website with one settings.py

Tags: django, deployment, internationalization

Currently I am running a multi language website.

```
example.com
example.it
example.at
example.ch
…
example.fr
```

I use the sites framework and run each website in a different docker container like described here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

> In order to serve different sites in production, you’d create a
> separate settings file with each SITE_ID (perhaps importing from a
> common settings file to avoid duplicating shared settings) and then
> specify the appropriate DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for each site.

I have a global settings.py and for each website I create a custom settings.py which imports the settings from the global settings.py

```
├── ...
├── urls.py
├── settings.py
├── sites
│   ├── examplecom.py
│   ├── exampleit.py
│   ├── exampleat.py
│   ├── examplech.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── examplefr.py
├── ...
└── wsgi.py
```

Here is an example how my custom examplepl.py file looks like.

```
from myapp.settings import *

SITE_ID             = 19
LANGUAGE_CODE       = SITEID_INFO[SITE_ID]['language']
COUNTRY_CODE        = SITEID_INFO[SITE_ID]['country']
ALPHABET_CHARACTERS = SITEID_INFO[SITE_ID]['alphabet']

SITE_RELATED_COUNTRIES = ['PL']

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL          = SITEID_INFO[SITE_ID]['default_from_email']
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL_NAME     = SITEID_INFO[SITE_ID]['default_from_email_name']

SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd.m.Y'

SOME_TOKEN = 'foobar'

AVAILABLE_ORDER_PACKAGES = [28, 5, 6, 29, 14, 15, 30, 23, 24 ]

PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE = "PLN"
PAYMENTOPTION['przelewy24'] = True
...
```

As you can see, I hardcoded the language for each website and setting some specific variables which change the behavior for each language version.(access tokens, currency, payment methods and so on…)
(We also use wagtail, but this is out of scope which already shows the content dynamically)

1.) How can I change the language dynamically? Is there something like the Locale Middleware which changes the language only depending on the domain name?

2.) Can I change with a middleware the variables in  my settings.py depending from the calling domain url?
Currently I create for each domain a new docker container and let it run. At the beginning this was not a problem, but we started to translate the website to server countries and it is a nightmare to run so many instances.

The goal is, to run only one docker container which can serve all website versions.

Comment: Quick question. Do you need multiple domains? If so, you need to setup a server to handle them, like NGINX. If you only need translation based on user's browsers language, Django has this built in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/translation/ if you must use different domains I have a solution here with NGINX and Django Middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77434775/8382028

Comment: Yes I need multiple domains for each language. The LocaleMiddleware described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware is a nightmare from an SEO perspective. Just imagine you google for english content and get on the website and you see something in french because your browser is french.